# Laravel ErrorException: Undefined variable: errors in \storage\framework\views\

Tags: php, laravel

I´m trying to use redis queues to delay sending mail, but every time I get the error:

> ErrorException: Undefined variable: errors in
>   C:\wamp64\www\laravel\boltra\storage\framework\views\c653bafa95fad21933516563a0de08b10beb4f05.php:92

I´m using Laravel 5.8, so I´m pretty sure all my routes are inside the 'web' middleware group, and my email template is also correct.
This works:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->bcc(env('MAIL_MY_EMAIL'))->send(new BienvenidoABoltra($user, 'bienvenida_e_autoregistro'));
```

These don´t:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->bcc(env('MAIL_MY_EMAIL'))->queue(new BienvenidoABoltra($user, 'bienvenida_e_autoregistro'));
Mail::to($user->email)->bcc(env('MAIL_MY_EMAIL'))->later($when, new BienvenidoABoltra($user, 'bienvenida_e_autoregistro'));
```

I tested redis with a simple logger and works fine too...

```
dispatch(function(){
  logger('Hola!!');
})->delay(now()->addSeconds(10));
```

What am I missing?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried clearing the views cache? `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. I did, but still got the same result... other ideas? By the way, I´ve tried with different email templates, and none of them work when sent through the queue, even though they all work fine with a simple send(). Also, I don´t require the errors variable myself for any of those views, I´m guessing it´s a Laravel´s temp view looking for the system´s errors bag, and unable to find it.