# Laravel: Send email using queue and jobs

Tags: laravel, email, queue, jobs

I want to send email using laravel queue. I follow tutorial from this site https://blog.mailtrap.io/laravel-mail-queue/ . It is work (email can be send using job and queue).

But i want to include value in the email. Below are the code that i modify to send the value.

I thought `$details` array will carry the value and pass to the email template. But when i run, the job is failed. Is there any way that i could improve?

PController.php

```
$details = array(
            'email' => 'test@mail.com',
            'fruitname' => 'watermelon',
            'fruitid' => 'F001'
        );

dispatch(new SendEmail($details))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10));
```

Mailable Class: SendEmail.php

```
protected $details;

public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

public function handle()
    {
        $email = new MailFruit();
        Mail::to($this->details['email'])->send($email);
    }
```

MailFruit.php

```
protected $details;

public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('admin@mail.com')
                    ->subject('New Fruit')
                    ->view('emails/email_fruit_template')
                    ->with('details', $this->details);
    }
```

email_fruit_template.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')

New Fruit Details

Fruit ID: {{ $details['fruitid'] }}
Fruit Name: {{ $details['fruitname'] }}

Fruit Company
@endcomponent
```

Any help will be grateful. Thank you.

Edit:
This one appear on cmd.

```
$php artisan queue:work
[2020-08-12 14:36:22][58] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmail
[2020-08-12 14:36:23][58] Failed:     App\Jobs\SendEmail
```

Comment: you are not passing that array to the new instance of `MailFruit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass details array in the new instance of Mailfruit.

```
public function handle()
    {
        $email = new MailFruit($this->details);
        Mail::to($this->details['email'])->send($email);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to pass details array, but the email job is till failed.

Comment: [2020-08-12 14:36:23][58] Failed:     App\Jobs\SendEmail.

Comment: Seems like there is no value passes to the email template

Comment: Can you provide more details on the error. it could be hundrads of reason why your job is failing. 

just update your question.

Comment: and? Do you think you can copy the error and show us here ?

Comment: On failed jobs table, exception column it show this error.  ErrorException: Undefined variable: details in C:\xampp\htdocs\fruit\storage\framework\views\5f006e8ae75448086fc15e1b2ff7ae532e995119.php:6

Comment: make the $details public and try again. let me know.

Comment: At first, I only make $details public on MailFruit.php. The jobs is still failed. Then i try removing $details['value'] on email template to not receiving any value. The job can be run and email are being send. Is there possibility the way i write $details['value'] in email template is wrong?

Comment: I think my problem related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089937/laravel-errorexception-undefined-variable-errors-in-storage-framework-views @fahim152

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219720/discussion-between-malca-and-fahim152).